# ORDER BY and Aliased COUNT() in One query

Tags: sql

```
          POSTS
[ id -   post   -  content ]
----------------------------
[ 1  -  1post1  - 1content1]
[ 2  -  1post2  - 2content2]



        VOTES
   [ id -  pid]
   ------------
   [ 1  -    1]
   [ 2  -    1]
   [ 3  -    1]
   [ 4  -    2]
   [ 5  -    2]

1post1 = 3 votes
2post2 = 2 votes
```

When i try this query

```
$query = "SELECT a.title, a.content, b.COUNT(id) FROM posts a, votes b WHERE id = :id ORDER BY b.COUNT(id)";
```

it doesn't work and gives me this error

```
FUNCTION b.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution
```

Is there is a better way to do this? I thought about using `UNION ALL` to be like this

```
$query = "SELECT title, content, COUNT(id) FROM posts WHERE id = :id
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM votes WHERE pid = :id";
```

but the problem here i won't be able to use `ORDER BY COUNT(id)` for the first part, Which is what i want to order it depending on the second part.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to select `posts` ordered by the number of `votes`? What's the table structure?

Comment: do you mean `count(b.id)`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol putted an example table.

Comment: @xQbert in my voting table, Which i just added now, The post id will be registered as a row for each vote, without a value, So when the post id has 10 rows with its id in `VOTES` table, The query will count it as 10 votes and order the posts using the votes in the first part of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It looks like there's a relation between posts/votes so the join is needed.  a cross join which is what you're doing now seems incorrect.  as it would take the results (2) from post and (5) from results and multiply them giving you 10 records.  You need a join so that the postID from votes is referenced.
2. count is a function so it gets used as count(table.field) to count values in a  specific column or count(*) just to count the number of records in a table.
3. When joining two tables; be sure to alias the columns (in your case ID exists in both so specifying what table ID you're after matters.
4. when using an aggregate such as `COUNT()` a group by is needed if you have non-aggregated fields (Such as ID or post in your example)

So maybe... (ANSI 92)

```
SELECT P.ID, P.Post, count(V.ID) as No_Votes
FROM Posts P 
INNER JOIN Votes V
 on V.PID = P.ID
WHERE  P.ID = :id
GROUP BY P.ID, P.Post
ORDER BY No_votes  -- due to order of operation we can use the column alias in an order by.
```

Or... (ANSI 87)

```
SELECT P.ID, P.Post, count(V.ID) as No_Votes
FROM Posts P, Votes V
WHERE V.PID = P.ID
  AND P.ID = :id
GROUP BY P.ID, P.Post
ORDER BY No_votes
```

Maybe you want all posts even those w/o votes so perhaps you need to use an OUTER JOin (Right /left instead of inner depending on what you're after: your example and expected results don't show anything but an inner so I started here)

Comment: What is the difference exactly between `FROM table x, table y` and `FROM table x INNER JOIN table y`?

Comment: x,y are `cross join` ( no criteria relating X,y) thus you get 10 records.  `INNER JOIN` on... shows a relation so the # of records can't exceed the # of records in one  of the tables.  So 5 records at most could be returned and since we're grouping by the x side and counting the y side, we'd only get 2 records back.  The cross join would marry all X to all Y so Post1 would be associated to votes 1-5 and Post2 would be associated to votes 1-5 as well.  I don't think that's what you're after given the expected results in your question.

Comment: `,` notation is also ANSI 87 standards where as `INNER JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN` are ANSI 92 standards  both work; just don't mix them.  Since you didn't have a where clause saying how x/y relate in your example, a cross join result is encountered.

Comment: Is there any advantage from using ANSI92 over ANSI87? like performance? Or is it just a taste subject?

Comment: The consensus for most is that ANSI92 is easier to read/maintain.  (subject to taste) Performance wise a good engine should optimize to the same plan; so no benefit.  However in your case 10 records vs  vs 5... vs 2 the method of join matters here since a cross join would give you incorrect results IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the b. from before count(id)...you are using a function, not a table alias.

Comment: It is two different table related.

Comment: @CaliburVictorious your statement is wrong.. as cbell said, you need to remove the b from b.count(...), it should be count(b.id)

Comment: No. The answer is spot on. You must remove the prefix from the aggregate function. It is COUNT(b.id) - not b.COUNT(id).

Comment: @fabricio Oh, i understood it now, I thought he meant to remove the b. from the entire query.

Comment: Additionally you may want to add a join condition like a.id = b.post_id. Or you will get wrong results.